# Copy Command/Powershell Window screen buffer

Tags: c++, c, powershell, command-prompt

I want to copy the screen buffer of the command/powershell window to a text file using C/C++/Powershell.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Host console API:-

```
$rec = new-object System.Management.Automation.Host.Rectangle 0,0,($host.ui.rawui.BufferSize.Width  - 1),$host.ui.rawui.CursorPosition.Y
$buffer = $host.ui.rawui.GetBufferContents($rec)
```

Write buffer to file using >> or |

Answer (score 0):

What about using `Start-Transcript` and `Stop-Transcript` ?

[Technet: Create a Transcript of What You Do in Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff687007.aspx)